# Laravel 8 deploy to heroku failed on Pusher.php ($auth_key)

Tags: laravel-8, heroku-cli

```
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
remote:        
remote:        In Pusher.php line 63:
remote:
remote:          Pusher\Pusher::__construct(): Argument #1 ($auth_key) must be of type strin    
remote:          g, null given, called in /tmp/build_fb8ecd51/vendor/laravel/framework/src/I    
remote:          lluminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php on line 218
```

Here is my .env pusher configuration. I have "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.0" installed and tried change it to other version but still not working.

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1368435
PUSHER_APP_KEY=fe949b1c86852b82bc6e
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=117bc32cf87c7d0b37f1
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to your app on **heroku** -> **settings**->**Reveal Config Vars**->
then add this with key and value

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1368435
PUSHER_APP_KEY=fe949b1c86852b82bc6e
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=117bc32cf87c7d0b37f1
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=ap1
```

hopefully that is help you

Comment: Oh thanks, that saved my time.. already tried it earlier but I only added the pusher app key and not the whole pusher configuration.